# Installing Plone package as offline zip / tar.gz in buildout

Tags: plone, buildout

I'd like to distribute Plone package as offline zip / .tar.gz archive, as the deployment environment, with readily prepared Plone 4.x installation, lacks internet access at the moment.

What would be the best way to do it?

- Shall I package my (Archeypes) package as Python egg, zip / tar.gz and how? Is it `python setup.py sdist` or something else?
- How on include this package in `buildout.cfg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We commonly use the "pypi-local" approach: just put a path to local directory (inside buildout, or somewhere else) as a buildout `find-links`.

See our buildout: https://github.com/RedTurtle/deployments.buildout.plone/blob/a1595768db77686364f663c90d47a0b481803d9c/config/base.cfg#L14

Only a doubt: I fear that running "bin/buildout -No" (offline mode enabled) will not recognize the pypi-local directory as local.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be roll your own Unified Installer.

1. Fork the UI from github and clone your fork;
2. Add your package to the buildout template;
3. Install from the installer clone directory;
4. Rerun buildout from the target directory to pick up the missing
   package;
5. Use the UI's "update" script to update the UI's buildout cache;
6. Use it's "build" script to create your own installer tarball.

The new installer tarball will have everything it needs to build Plone offline.